# Make predictions from a trained classifier python #Scikitlearn #SVM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification, predict

I need help classifying unseen data. I have a sample set of data.

```
    ID         Comment                Category
    2017_01    inadequate stock       Availability
    2017_02    Too many failures      Quality
    2017_03    no documentation       Customer Service
    2017_04    good product           Satisfied
    2017_05    long delivery times    Delivery
```

I have trained a multilevel text classifier using this data. 
I tested the fit of data using MultinomialNB and SVM and I have chosen SVM as the final model

```
# Support Vector Machines - calculating the SVM Fit
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
text_clf_svm = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()), ('tfidf', 
TfidfTransformer()),('clf-svm', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', 
penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5, random_state=42))])

text_clf_svm = text_clf_svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted_svm = text_clf_svm.predict(X_train)
np.mean(predicted_svm == y_train)
0.8850102669404517
```

I tested the model on a comment from this year

```
print(text_clf_svm.predict(["This is obsolete and being replaced by another product. not very robust and we have had many failures"]))
```

['Quality']

**Question: How do I pass in the unseen data from 2018 (Below) to get classified as above?**

```
   ID          Comment                            Category
   2018_01     This product is obsolete 
   2018_02     Tech Support takes too long  
   2018_03     2 out of 3 products failed   
   2018_04     Delivery to APAC takes too long
```

Comment: Replace all pictures with text please.

Comment: Just pass the comments column to `text_clf_svm()` and put the results from that into the category column

Comment: Thank you Vivek, I passed in the comment section to i.e: category= text_clf_svm(df[Comment]) how do I construct a data frame that contains the newly predicted category, and the ID?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the solution. If I want to map the prediction results back to the original data frame, I have to add the new column to the old data frame

```
#Bring in new data and predict
import pandas as pd
df_p = pd.read_csv("comment_to_predict.csv", sep = ',', usecols = range(2), encoding='iso-8859-1')

#Map the predictions to the original data frame (df_p in my case)
df_p['category'] = text_clf_svm.predict(df_p['comment'])
```